# Как отсортировать большой файл. Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать сортировку большого файла.
Я не понимаю как для большого файла, в котооом хранятся строки на кириллице организовать сортировку. Какие типы данных для этого использовать. 
Файл более 50 000 000 строк . Формат txt.

Comment: Не ясна ваша проблема. Если в строке в 60-80 символов, то 50 миллионов строк дают 300-400 Мбайт данных. Это вполне подъёмно даже для 32-битной программы. В Delphi есть встроенный обобщённый тип `TList`, у которого есть метод `Sort`. Загружаете построчно файл в `TList<String>`, сортируете, выводите результат в другой файл.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неясности. Размер файла от 500 мегабайт до 10 гигабайт . Как показала практика,  100 мегабайт это примерно 1000000 строк

Comment: Даже 10 гигабайт можно сортировать в памяти, если пишете 64-битное приложение. Насколько я знаю, Delphi лет 5 как поддерживает 64-битные приложения. На современных компьютерах разработчиков 16 гигабайт есть у всех. Ваша программа займёт строк 15 кода и будет выполняться может быть минуты полторы, из которых 40 секунд займёт сортировка.

Comment: В крайнем случае сортируйте слиянием - самое оно для сортировки массивов, не влезающих в память. Порубите файл на куски, которые можно полностью принять в память и отсортировать.

Comment: Задание необходимо выполнить на Delphi 7 к сожалению

Answer (score 2):

Раз это задание, то оно подразумевает примерно то, что написал Akina.

Читайте из огромного файла строки в `TStringList`, но не все сразу, а с помощью `AssignFile-Reset-Readln` добавляйте, пока не наберёте разумное для сортировки количество (например, миллион строк, или сто мегабайт по объёму).

Отсортируйте встроенной сортировкой и запишите в первый файл. Продолжайте создавать сортированные куски, пока большой файл не кончится.

Теперь заведите структуру данных "binary heap"  - кучу, и с её помощью выбирайте наименьшие строки из всех файлов, записывайте в единый выходной файл, он будет сортирован.

Comment: Есть небольшая проблема ) не думал что к этому дойдёт, так как я поменял вектор своего решения после ваших комментариев ) спасибо вам ) я пытался сортировать список быстрой сортировкой по 100 мегабайт. Выскакивала ошибка . Но вот зачем она была нужна . Строка представляет собой следующий вид. 1233.текст . И условие сортировки заключается в том что сортируются строки по текстовой части, а если они одинаковые, то сравниваем числовые части .

Comment: В таком случае нужно использовать `СustomSort` со своей функцией сравнения

Comment: классическое слияние все равно будет в нехватку памяти упираться в конце. так что сливая тоже придется читать блоками

Comment: @teran Достаточно в памяти держать по одной строчке из каждого "мелкого" файла

Comment: @MBo достаточно, да